# Метод sort в функциях

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите, осваиваю кодварс и была задачка:

> Create a function that returns the sum of the two lowest positive numbers given an array of minimum 4 positive integers. No floats or non-positive integers will be passed.

```
  numbers = numbers.sort(function(a, b){return a - b; });
  return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
};
```

собственно мое решение было практически таким же, но возникли вопросы:

1. в начале функции я не присваивал `numbers = numbers.sort`. Результат один и тот же, тогда зачем оно тут функционально?
2. в комментариях сказали, что это дурная практика и не решает проблему с плавающей запятой и отрицательными(хотя я подставил и все вроде как работало). В чем тогда загвоздка?

Comment: Первый вопрос не ясен. При sort присваивание в переменную не нужно

Comment: Почему на второй вопрос вам не ответил тот, кто указал на ошибки?

Comment: Если в массиве будет больше  одного отрицательного числа то ответ будет неверный в рамках задания

Comment: Потому что эти замечания я прочитал в комментариях, написанных год назад. Подумал что там это спрашивать бессмысленно за истечением срока. Спасибо